# Filemaker or web framework?

Tags: web-frameworks, filemaker, database-driven

I have to build many data-driven web application for various clients. The aim is to build quickly CRUD screens with ACL (based upon tables and fields).

I'm looking for the pros and cons of every solutions (Filemaker or a web framework like Grails).

Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's easier to set up a web framework like the RubyOn Rails i use every day . 
But it depends on your skills....

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm trying with Grails, and it seems to be ok

Comment: I saw that Symfony offers a very powerfull CRUD admin area (http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/14-Generators). RoR can do  the same thing ?